# MKMapView crashes the app when app is run in Xcode on a device but not if running on device by application icon tap

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have this case where I implemented MKMapView in .xib file. I connected IBOutlet in class with MKMapView in .xib file. iOS on device is 8.3. When app is build and run by Xcode on device, it crashes when I open view controller with MKMapView, but it doesn't crash if I run the application on tap on it's icon on the device. I get no exception or error in log. It's only breaks at main. I commented code for MKMapView IBOutlet but nothing changes, only if I remove MKMapView from .xib file crash is gone. Code is written in Swift. How to fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to run the app from Xcode but with disabling all breakpoints?

Comment: did you use the mapkit.framework ?

Comment: Yes I tried to run app with disabling all breakpoints but it's all the same and I use the mapkit.framework.

Answer (score 1):

Hope these points may help:

1. You can try to run it in Release mode , If there there is any
   breakpoints issue.
2. You can check whether you are assigning delegates to the owner or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, but I solved it to add mapkit.framework to project.